# Problems using main(int argc,char *argv[])

Tags: c, program-entry-point, argv

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char string[]="#";
    printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n",argv[2]);
    printf("%s\n",argv[3]);
    strcat(argv[1],string);
    printf("argv[1] is %s\n",argv[1]);
    printf("argv[2] is %s\n",argv[2]);
    printf("argv[3] is %s\n",argv[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

when I use strcat() to add something to the end of the argv[1],argv[2] will be lost( strlen(argv[2]) changes to 0 after use strcat ).But argv[3] has no change .Why???

Comment: What is this code doing o.O'

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963493/is-it-possible-to-change-argv-or-do-i-need-to-create-an-adjusted-copy-of-it

Comment: @Thomas This code is just to solve my question with argv[].It can do nothing meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot append stuff directly to `argv[]` because each `argv[]` is allocated serialized and to a space in memory that can only hold its original size.

To understand what is happening, imagine `argv` is something like this:

```
char buffer[] = "./program\0one\0two\0three\0";
char *argv[4] = { &buffer[0], &buffer[10], &buffer[14], &buffer[18] };
```

So as you can see, if you write something after `"one"` you will overwrite `"two"` and break the whole thing because they are serialized in memory.

To workaround this, you have to copy each `argv[]` to a bigger buffer where you can safely make the modifications. For instance:

```
char buf[1024];
strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
strcat(buf, string);
printf("argv[1] is %s\n", buf);
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that "strings" in C are zero terminated arrays of characters. Suppose the original four arguments were "one", "two", "three" and "four"; then these four arguments are stored in memory as

```
one\0two\0three\0four\0
```

when you appended # after the argv[1] (strcat will add a \0 also), the memory content becomes:

```
one\0two#\0hree\0four\0
```

you can now verify that argv[2] points to the \0 char, hence it is a empty string. argv[3] still points correctly, and it remains intact.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to modify argv[] = the effects are undefined

Comment: I think so too, but is there any reference?

Comment: Actually, you _can_ modify `argv[whatever]` (the pointer). Modifying what the pointer points to is not so kosher.

Comment: @paxdiablo: So, is it like `char const * argv[]`?

Comment: No it's not necessarily const - the standard doesn't say what it has to be. Just that the memory isn't yours so you shouldn't change it.