# Trying to copy a file to a directory. But the file clears itself. (c)

Tags: c, file-io

For example i have a file test1.txt that has inside "this is a test file". 
and i have a directory /testDir. If i run this as ./cp2 test1.txt /testDir
The program will run but test1.txt will become empty, as well as /testDir/test1.text will become empty. Can anyone identify where in my code im overwriting the contents of both text files?

Thankyou in advance.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // for strtol
#include <string.h>

#define COPYMODE 0644 
#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
void errExit(char*, char*);
void copyFile(char *src, char* dest) {

int srcFd;
int dstFd;
int charCnt;
    char buf[BUFFERSIZE];

/*Check args*/

/*Open the files*/
if( (srcFd=open(src, O_RDONLY)) == -1){
    errExit("Cannot open ", src);
}
if( (dstFd=creat(dest, COPYMODE)) ==-1) {
errExit("Cannot create ", dest);
}
/*Copy the data*/
while( (charCnt= read(srcFd, buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0 ){
    if( write(dstFd,buf,charCnt ) != charCnt ){
    errExit("Write error to ", dest);
}
}
if( charCnt==-1 ){
    errExit("Read error from ", src);
}

/*Close files*/
if ( close(srcFd) == -1 || close(dstFd) == -1 ){
    errExit("Error closing files","");
 }

}

main(int argC, char* argV[]) {

char* src = argV[1];
char* dest = argV[2];

if(src[0] != '/' && dest[0] != '/' ) {
copyFile(src, dest);
} else if(src[0] !='/' && dest[0] == '/') { //going to change this to check if its a dir or file.
int i;
for(i=1; i<=strlen(dest); i++) {
    dest[(i-1)] = dest[i];
        }

    strcat(dest, "/");
    strcat(dest, src);
    copyFile(dest, src);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Sidenote: you forgot to include <io.h>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

---

Your definition of `COPYMODE` is wrong, you need this:

```
#define COPYMODE S_IRWXU|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH
```

read the documentation of [`creat`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/creat)

---

This is probably not a good idea:

```
strcat(dest, "/");
strcat(dest, src);
```

here you modify the string pointed by `dest`. This is OK but only if the new string is not longer than the one pointed by `dest`, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963493/is-it-possible-to-change-argv-or-do-i-need-to-create-an-adjusted-copy-of-it).

You need another buffer for the string you construct:

```
char destfilename[300];
strcpy(destfilename, dest);
strcat(destfilename, "/");
strcat(destfilename, src);
copyFile(destfilename, src);
```

Comment: Fixed it by changing COPYMODE to COPYMORE Cheers for the info though. I also dont have <io.h>

Comment: OK <io.h> is a Microsoftism, I removed it from the answer.

Comment: BTW: this code `for(i=1; i<=strlen(dest); i++) {
    dest[(i-1)] = dest[i];
        }` is also rather fishy, you may need to check this.