# Why does the printf of ++**++argv output 'p'?

Tags: c, command-line

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    printf("%c",++**++argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Suppose the command line arguments passed were:

```
./a.out one two three
```

The output is:

```
p
```

Can someone please explain me what is happening?

Comment: Don't write bull#%&t code like this.

Comment: The letter `p` is equals to `o + 1`. `one` is the parameter with index 1.

Comment: @MichaelWalz True, but maybe this is a riddle to teach the basics?

Comment: @PatrickBucher not sure if this is the right way to teach basics.

Comment: @MichaelWalz At least an exercise in reading bad code ;-)

Comment: @MichaelWalz teaching this is not teaching basics, it's teaching very bad practices and should not be welcomed on SO, besides, SO is not primarily a site for free tuition.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, it's bad practice, and yes SO is not a site for free tuition, but it is still interesting to understand why languages behave they way they do when you abuse them.

Comment: @klutt  It might be interesting to some, but it's not generally useful to future SO users/visitors.  There are some homework/quiz questions that can be interesting AND useful.  This is not one of them.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I think this snippet is a coding puzzle. It has no practical uses aside from providing a somewhat nerdy entertainment to its readers.

Comment: It is perfectly clear what the question is asking. Putting it on hold as "unclear" makes zero sense to me. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 6):

Start from the back of the `++**++argv` expression:

- `argv` starts off as a pointer to element zero, i.e. `"./a.out"` or `""`
- `++argv` is `char**` that points to string `"one"`
- `*++argv` is `char*` that points to string `"one"`'s initial element
- `**++argv` is `char` that is equal to string `"one"`s initial element, i.e. `'o'`
- `++**++argv` is `char` that follows `'o'`. On most systems that's `'p'`.

The last operation modifies program's arguments in place, which is allowed by the standard ([Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/963493/335858)).