# access to process' arguments outside main()

Tags: c, arguments

Is it possible to access process' arguments elsewhere than inside `main` function ?

I am in a situation where I can't add code in `main` function. A test software create for me a test driver program and I can add code only inside specific part of test driver program (that is not main function). I want, in this code, change process arguments (to be precise, I want to change process name after a fork…)

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you make a variable global?

Comment: @FiddlingBits it is a very clear question, the `main` cannot be touched.

Comment: Linux, windows …. ?

Comment: The process name is the process name - not something you can change. You can know if the you are the child fork, and show a different value. You can access the values, but I would not try changing them

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If you say so.

Comment: @lostbard Unix. Linux. The process name can very much be changed. `argv` is writable.

Comment: A duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963493/is-it-possible-to-change-argv-or-do-i-need-to-create-an-adjusted-copy-of-it ?

Comment: @lostbard nope.

Comment: Can't you just assign argv[0] and exec() yourself? (given you have the correct path/name to the binary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no portable way to access the value of `argv` other than saving it on entry to `main()`, which is not possible under the conditions of the question.

However, non-portable solutions exist for most operating systems, based on the expected layout of the initial stack. For example, the following should work on Linux (but no guarantees, neither explicit nor implied):

```
#include <stdint.h>
/* This code is unsafe and unportable. But it might work for you. */
char** getargv(void) {
  extern char** environ;
  char **argv = environ - 1;
  for (char** e = argv; (uintptr_t)(argv[-1]) != e - argv; --argv) { }
  return argv;
}
```

That code comes from reverse-engineering the stack created [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L308). It assumes that `environ` still has the value assigned at startup, which may not be the case if the application has called `setenv` or `putenv` before this function is called. (Those are pretty rare, though.) For reference, the relevant part of the stack looks like this (all entries are the size of a pointer):

```
argc
argv[0]
...
argv[argc - 1]
0
environ[0]
...
0
```

The loop starts at the NULL terminating the `argv` array and looks backwards until it comes across an integer which would be a correct value for `argc`. It could be fooled by an address which looks like an integer but in Linux that is extremely unlikely because the addresses used for the argv strings are never small enough to be confused with a small integer.

---

The code above is written as a function but in the context of the question that might not be possible. Obviously, it could just be copied into some other function, so it's not a problem.

However, if you are able to insert a function and a global into the executable, you can take advantage of the usual (but not universal) implementation of constructor functions, using the GCC/Clang `constructor` function attribute. Any such functions are executed prior to `main()` being called, and are passed the same arguments as `main()` is passed. This should work at least on Linux and OS X, and quite possibly other Unix-like systems:

```
char** saved_argv;
int saved_argc; 
void saveargv(int argc, char** argv) __attribute__((constructor)) {
  saved_argc = argc;
  saved_argv = argv;
}
```

Comment: Yuck :D that's awful :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: You got a more elegant solution?

Comment: Nope, I looked into the ELF auxv too but couldn't figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution only for linux, use /proc/NNN/cmdline.
Example :

```
int pid;
char procPathName[256];
int fcl;

pid = getpid();
snprintf(procPathName, 255, "/proc/%ld/cmdline", pid);
fcl = open(procPathName, 0);
if (fcl == -1)
{
  /* error */
}
else
{
  char buffer[1024];
  int bufferLen;
  bufferLen = read(fcl, buffer, 1023);
  close(fcl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can backtrace the stack and go upto to main(if you can find it), there u get arg values then change them