# Working with char pointer -> Segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, char, segmentation-fault, fault

Im a beginner and at school we have task to split a char array by using pointer. I want to split the name and the birthday (delimiter = '.'). My solution works perfect for the name but doing it for the birthday i get a segmentation fault.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *fullname;
    char *name;
    char *lastname;
    char *birthday;
    char *day;
    fullname = argv[1];
    birthday = argv[2];
    int i = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;

    while(fullname[i] != '.'){
        char x = fullname[i];
        name[i] = x;
        fullname[i] = ' ';
        i++;
    }
    i++;

    while(fullname[i] != '\0'){
        char x = fullname[i];
        lastname[y] = x;
        fullname[i] = ' ';
        i++;
        y++;
     }

    while(birthday[z] != '.'){
         char b = birthday[z];  
         day[z] = b;
         z++;
    }
}
```

Input in commandline (./a is the exe file on cygwin):

```
./a mister.gold 11.05.2005
```

Output:

```
segmentation fault
```

When i launch the code without the last loop my output is:

```
mister
gold
```

Comment: `name`, `lastname` and friends are not initialized to point to any valid memory.

Comment: You can't use an uninitialized `char*` pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks for the reply , but why does it work when i remove the last loop?

Comment: It doesn't. It's *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You should check that `argc == 3`, if not, for example, print an error and `return EXIT_FAILURE` (defined in `stdlib.h`) or in general, non-zero. Also, you might check that `'.'` and `'\0'` are not encountered. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/963777/2472827.

Comment: If you compiled with warnings turned on, the compiler would let you know that name, lastname and day are all used without being initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *name ;
char *lastname;
```

Two char array pointer , but what do they point two? nothing so you are basically trying to access a memory you don't own
to allocate memory for them you should do :

```
 // assuming the maximum size if 512 for example or you can give it any size you think is enough
 char *name =malloc(512);
 char *lastname=malloc(512);
```

now they point to something you can access & modify

after you are done using them you should deallocate the dynamic allocated memory like this

```
free(lastname); 
free(name);
```

Comment: thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: You could even do it in place as well by assignment of `name`, `lastname` to spots in `argv[1]`, but they need to be assigned somewhere writable.